# expected identifier or '(' before '.' token ../texture-atlas.c

Tags: c, freetype

[image]I am trying to build a Github repository(https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl) using cmake. The below error shows up:

> expected identifier or '(' before '.' token ../texture-atlas.c

Background: The folder contains a file called texture-atlas.c which has just this one line:

```
../texture-atlas.c
```

There is also a file by the same name in the parent directory which is being referred. How do I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Error also told you where is this problem. So show us this part of code.

Comment: There is no code. There is a file by the name texture-atlas.c. And what it contains is: ../texture-atlas.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is supposed to be symbol link, pointing at the file `../texture-atlas.c` (i.e. [this file](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/blob/master/texture-atlas.c)).

In Linux, symbolic links are represented as text files containing the path to the link target, and a special meta-info flag in the file system that says "this is a symbolic link". That's why you get the target file name as the contents of the file, that's all that remains when the link flag doesn't exist.

You probably cloned the repo on a platform not supporting symbolic links. Try copying the file over the link.

Edit:

[The installation instructions for Windows](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/blob/master/INSTALL.md#windows-msys2-mingw64-with-gcc-64-bit-toolchain) say:

> Note: Harfbuzz examples only work with symbolic links enabled. See https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-links.

So you should probably follow that link, and see what to do.

Comment: So, I am on windows. And I have followed the installation instructions corresponding to windows. Could you please direct me as to how the symbolic link has to be enabled?